# Phoenix: Requiring IEx in only :dev and :test for entire project

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-iex

I'm new to Elixir/Phoenix and I was wondering if there was a way to essentially `require IEx` for the purpose of `IEx.pry` in the same manner that in Ruby/Rails you can add something like

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'pry', require: 'pry'
end
```

which would allow you to `binding.pry` in essentially any file without needing to include `require 'pry'`

I'm finding that having to `require IEx` on any controller, model, view, etc I want to debug to be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `web/web.ex` file.

> A module that keeps using definitions for controllers,   views and
>   so on.
>
> This can be used in your application as:
>
> ```
> use App.Web, :controller
> use App.Web, :view
> ```
>
> The definitions below will be executed for every view,   controller,
>   etc, so keep them short and clean, focused   on imports, uses and
>   aliases.

Just put `require IEx` here when you need it for controllers, models etc.

```
defmodule App.Web do
  def model do
    quote do
      ...
      require IEx
    end
  end
  def controller do
    quote do
      ...
      require IEx
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This will be done for `:prod` environment as well, which OP apparently doesn't want.

Comment: ^ Precisely.

I had previously done exactly as @droptheplot suggested. It's a work-around, but I was hoping for something more dev/test specific.

Comment: Can someone tell me why `if Mix.env == "dev", do: require IEx` does not work?

Comment: @Johannes When the compiler tries to expand the macro `IEx.pry` it has not yet evaluated the conditional (`if` being a macro itself). You can use `IEx.pry` in the same condition in which you `require IEx` though. Also note what the docs say for `Mix.html#env/0`: _This function should not be used at runtime in application code"_